# What is the other name for Maybe monad?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I know that in FP there are sometimes multiple terms to say one thing. So when I started to learn fp-ts API (https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/docs/index.md) I couldn't find Maybe monad. So maybe there is another name for it?

Comment: It's `Option` there

Comment: Wow. 17 seconds. Good :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the other name for Maybe monad?

`Option` : https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/docs/Option.md

Comment: Thank you, Basarat. BTW I love your TS articles :-)

Comment: Cheers. Primarily `Option` cause of .Net developers being familiar with it from F# : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/options